# How best in an interview to say I'm leaving my job because of company reorganization?

Tags: interviewing

I'd like to say to the interviewer what the reason of why I leave the company.

The reason is that organization of the company changed, especially my team's organization.
But I don't have any idea. How to tell this to interviewer?
Would you please let me know ?
The skills and the better expression.

Comment: What do you mean by corruption? Do you want to emphasize the bad, evil part, or just the change?

Comment: @nvoigt Corruption means that just change

Comment: have you already left your company?

Answer (score 5):

The "corruption" (the word you used in a previous edit) of a previous company is probably not what you want to bring up in an interview unless you have to.  It's negative and makes the company wonder how you will speak of them when you leave.

In this case I would just describe it as it is,  your role changed so much that it became something different to the position you took in the first place and what it became wasn't something you were interested in.  Be positive in explaining changes though.

You can perhaps mention that the company changed so much that it wasn't a company you felt motivated working for but again you are walking a thin line between someone with ideals and someone who's fickle.

Answer (score 2):

My concern about saying you left just because of a reorganization is that **ALL companies reorganize**. You don't want to give the impression that you are inflexible and unable to adjust to change or that you somehow believe changes should only be done if they have your specific approval first. That sort of attitude will eventually make you unemployable.

It is ok to describe that you were not happy with the new role you were assigned and why. For instance, In a reorganization, you may have been changed from doing Android development to automating QA processes. If your career goals are not in the QA areas, then moving is fine.

It is trickier if the reason why you want to leave is because you were assigned to work for a different boss on a new team, doing essentially the same thing. Big deal, happens all the time, I don't want to hire a special snowflake who can't handle it. In this case the old standby about wanting new challenges might serve you better than pointing out that you have difficulty getting along with people.

Personally just from your wording about corrupting the company (do not under any circumstances say that in an interview!!), I suspect you are not even going to give the change a fair try. You should do that though rather than run away. I was once re-organized to work for someone I resented. He turned out to be the best boss I ever had and the one who got me the highest pay raises I ever got. It is  a critical job skill to be able to adjust to change and you really should try before seeking out a new job just because the organization is different or you are assigned a new boss or new project responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've been fired, or are casting your departure in a negative way (e.g., blaming other people), the truth is that your future employer places less weight in an interview on why you are leaving, and it's best not to dwell on the details.

Best to say you are looking for a new opportunity because you do not feel professionally satisfied, or adequately challenged in your old/current job.

Avoid being negative, especially in regard to previous employers or co-workers. Focus on the future and what you can bring to the new company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you're right, I did not phrase that well. When I interview I also ask the question because the answer is important, and can make a difference. But unless that answer's a dealbreaker, most of the interview focuses on the future. My intent was to tell the OP that getting the details exactly right on the reason for leaving is less important overall.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the word "corruption" was thrown in there originally, although I don't see it in the current post. When providing reasons why you are leaving or have left the company, you will want to try to couch those reasons in ways that do not make it sound as though you are badmouthing the company. The danger in doing this is that the people you are speaking to might receive the information that you are presenting to them, but they are also receiving a loud and clear message that you are a person who talks badly about other organizations behind their proverbial back. This is an aspect of human nature that you must expect the other party to have, and also gets into the complicated nature of conversation, in which everything you say has 2 or more meanings all at once.

It is almost exactly the same reason why the family gossip is nearly always looked down upon. It's not that the rest of the family doesn't necessarily want to hear about all the juicy details, it's that when someone tells us a bad story, we associate them with the bad story, whether they are responsible for it or not.

Instead, I would recommend being circumspect about that, even using boring platitudes like "there was a reorganization and I found that I was not a fit for their culture anymore". If word later comes out - or heck, if they already know - that this company was a giant storm of crap, they will likely appreciate you for being tactful.